# ClassNotFound org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a Spring-Hibernate application in which I get this following exception with the root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am sure that I have properly configured everything.
I am using @autowired inside my controller (Annotation based) and also in my ServiceImpl classes.

Here is my controller.

```
package com.sarvika.sqexch;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.sarvika.sqexch.beans.QuestionBean;
import com.sarvika.sqexch.model.Question;
import com.sarvika.sqexch.service.QuestionService;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionService questionService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", "<font color=\"red\">"+formattedDate+"</font>" );
        model.addAttribute("questions", prepareListofBean(questionService.listQuestions()));

        return "home";
    }

    private List<QuestionBean> prepareListofBean(List<Question> questions){  
        List<QuestionBean> beans = null;  
        if(questions != null && !questions.isEmpty()){  
            beans = new ArrayList<QuestionBean>();  
            QuestionBean bean = null;  
            for(Question question : questions){  
                bean = new QuestionBean();  
                bean.setId(question.getId());  
                bean.setParent(question.getParent());  
                bean.setTitle(question.getTitle());  
                bean.setDescription(question.getDescription());  
                bean.setAsker_id(question.getAsker_id());  
                bean.setAccepted(question.getAccepted());
                beans.add(bean);  
            }  
        }  
        return beans;  
    }  

}
```

And my context configuration XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="/resources/database.properties" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">  
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" /> 
        <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">  
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">  
            <beans:list>  
                <beans:value>com.dineshonjava.model.Employee</beans:value>  
            </beans:list>  
        </beans:property>  
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <beans:props>  
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>  
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>  
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>     
            </beans:props>  
        </beans:property>  
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">  
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>  
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sarvika.sqexch" />

</beans:beans>
```

I'm pretty sure that I am doing something wrong. It would be great if one of you guys ca correct me... :D

EDIT:
I am using Maven. Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sarvika</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqexch</artifactId>
    <name>HelloSpring</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Aspects -->
        <dependency> 
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
             <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
             <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- org.hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- javax Persistence -->  
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
           <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so, post your `pom.xml`. If not, post the libraries you are using

Comment: Yes. I have Maven in my project...

Comment: Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the Hibernate Search dependency.

Comment: Now I'm getting NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Comment: Well this is a different problem now!

Comment: Why are you using 4 different Spring versions? Stick to one version, the latest possibly.

Comment: And Spring Boot if you're new to Spring instead of outdated XML.

Comment: In the POM? I catually picked everything from google...

Comment: Yeah I'm new to spring
Started it four days ago

Comment: Just go to start.spring.io and you can generate a complete, consistent, ready-to-run configuration.

Comment: That's not a solution for me
I want to know the exact cause so that I can solve related problems in upcoming future...

Comment: As I said, you are using Spring 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 4.0.3, 4.2.3 and 3.0.5 so that's actually 5 different version of Spring. Stick to 4.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a jar with the class `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`. You need to include this dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
```

And yes, as people say in comments - all your Spring dependencies need to be of one version. Otherwise there will be plenty of such errors.

Comment: Done. Now I'm getting `Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory'` this in my servlet-context.xml

Comment: Using spring-tx 4.2.3 breaks that